# Importing images dynamically from JSON file in reactJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

My json file: (items.json)

```
[
    {
        "title": "Nike shoes",
        "description": "New nike shoes",
        "price": "40$",
        "image": "../../../../assets/items/nike.jpg",
        "rank": "2"
    }
]
```

The file I'm trying to import the image in:

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
import Items from "../../../../items.json";

export default function ListedItems() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div class="container">
        {Items.map(item => (
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-heading">{item.title}</div>
              <div class="panel-body">
              <img
                  src={require(item.image)}
                  alt="Nike image"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I get this error "Error: Cannot find module '../../../../assets/items/nike.jpg'" 
, if I use src={require('../../../../assets/items/nike.jpg')} it works.

Comment: Please, could you include CodeSandbox to replicate and check?

Comment: Are you using webpack ?

Comment: What is the setup that you're using? Is it `create-react-app` or something similar? You shouldn't be doing `src={require(...)}` - it should be `src={item.image}` instead.

Comment: No not really using webpack, I have just read about it, I'll try it :)
Yes I used create-react-app, and the {item.image} doesnt work directly since it doesnt import the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you try to import your images in a runtime. 
You wrote, that you used `src={require('../../../../assets/items/nike.jpg')}` and it worked. But this code doesn't work.

Yes, you won't have an error in a browser console, but the image also won't load. Because `require()` function returns a `Promise`. And in this case, you will have in your browser:

```
<img src="[object Promise]" alt="Nike image">
```

1. You can resolve this issue by changing your `items.json` file from `json` to `js` and import images there.

```
import NikeImage from "../../../../assets/items/nike.jpg";
export const items = [
    {
        "title": "Nike shoes",
        "description": "New nike shoes",
        "price": "40$",
        "image": NikeImage,
        "rank": "2"
    }
]
```

and make some changes in your component:

```
<img src={item.image} alt="Nike image" />
```

But this code will only work if you are using `file-loader` in your webpack configuration.

2. In case when you have to use only `json` files or you get this information from the server. You should use [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin). If you use `create-react-app` (as you wrote in a comment), it already contains `CopyWebpackPlugin` and it copies your `public` folder. In this case just move your `assets` folder to `public` and change your `items.json` file

```
...
"price": "40$",
"image": "/assets/items/nike.jpg",
...
```

and your component:

```
<img src={item.image} alt="Nike image" />
```

Comment: the src={require('../../../../assets/items/nike.jpg')} did work, it did load the image into the browser.
I will try changing the json to js, although it was a requirement that I use a json file :/
Thanks!