# React App does not have media files in build

Tags: reactjs, require

I have a react application that is meant to display portfolio items on a page. When I run npm start they show up as expected, but on my production build (build folder) the media items are missing.

I am using require() to import the media based on a value in JSON.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export class PortfolioItem extends Component {
    render() {
        const { img_code, id } = this.props.item;
        return (
            <div className='portfolio__item'>
                <Link to={{
                    pathname: `/portfolio-details/${id}`
                }}>
                    <img
                        src={require(`../assets/img_items/${img_code}`).default}
                        alt=''
                        className='img img-item'
                    />
                </Link>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default PortfolioItem;
```

It is weird that this works fine locally but after git pulling the changes I made (the .default at the end) this does not work on my server.

Any ideas/comments welcome.

Comment: Are the media files  in the src file ?

Comment: [Have a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61341662/7704650)

Comment: @Qudusayo yes they are. Path URL is /src/assets/img_items/ ...

Comment: @emkarachchi the second recommendation is something I read elsewhere - move the images to the public folder. This seems a bit hacky but it might be the only solution.

Comment: Is  the local build  too failing to show the media files?

Comment: @Qudusayo local build is fine.

Comment: @user4889134 , thats not a proper solution and wont work  fine

Comment: @emkarachch where is the project hosted (netlify)   ? If  true, try vercel
One more, are the media  files successfully pushed  to githhub too ??

Comment: @Qudusayo hosted on digital ocean. Media files are not pushed to github. Here is the repo: https://github.com/james-zedd/robyn-zedd-portfolio-6549818961/

Comment: so after nearly a day of wrestling with Digital Ocean, I did the following: 1. restarted the server with sudo restart ... 2. deleted the build folder with rm -rf build ... 3. ran npm run build ... now everything works as expected. Only cost me a day and a lot of frustration.